# Swtich between GPS and Network?

Tags: java, android, gps

This code works perfectly for GPS:

```
public class GetLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager lm;
    TextView tv;  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_mission);


     // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationOutput);

        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, this);



    }
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        String lat = String.valueOf(arg0.getLatitude());
        String lon = String.valueOf(arg0.getLongitude());
        Log.e("GPS", "location changed: lat="+lat+", lon="+lon);
        tv.setText("lat="+lat+", lon="+lon);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        Log.e("GPS", "provider disabled " + arg0);
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        Log.e("GPS", "provider enabled " + arg0);
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        Log.e("GPS", "status changed to " + arg0 + " [" + arg1 + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_get_mission, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

However I want to get the location from Network not GPS. So I change:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, this);
```

to

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Then I get nothing. Is this down to an error in the code, or is it that the location doesn't change as frequently as it does with GPS therefore onLocationChange is never called? If I want to see the location at this time without a change should I use `.getLastKnownLocation` if so where can I call this so that it will update when the app starts?

Comment: Did you move for more than 3 km?

Comment: No, but I also set the limits all to 0: lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause could be that you have to move much more than in  GPS mode.
Try to move for some kilometers, and look if you still don't get an location update.

Try to set minTime to 6000 ms, meters i would set 10 or much more.
Check if you have to enable Network service.

Comment: How can I get the current location without moving km's?

Comment: Dont you get the initial location?

Comment: Further the 0,0 does not  look good. replace by something which makes more sense, e.g 1 m

Comment: No, I've done no more than appears in the code. Whats the method for getting the initial location?

Comment: set min time to 6000ms (android docu reccomendation), meter to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use LocationManager.isProviderEnabled() to see if the Network provider is enabled/disabled.

```
network_enabled=locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

and if it is disabled:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
```